# I keep getting a read error when copying stream data

Tags: delphi, stream

I am attempting to copy data from a `TStringStream` contained in a `TStreamReader` into another `TStringStream` using the `CopyFrom` method. If there have been no reads of the source stream it works as advertised, however if I perform a single read of the streamreader it throws an exception with EReadError: Stream read Error. Code to show problem:

```
program Project1;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}

{$R *.res}

uses
  System.SysUtils,
  System.classes;

var
  FStreamRead : TStreamReader;
  AChar : char;
  OutStream : TStringStream;

begin
  FStreamRead := TStreamReader.Create(TStringStream.Create('This is test data',TEncoding.UTF8));
  FStreamRead.OwnStream;
  try
    try
      // read once
      Achar := char (FStreamRead.Read);
      OutStream := TStringStream.Create;
      try
        OutStream.CopyFrom(FStreamRead.BaseStream,4);
      finally
        OutStream.Free;
      end;
    except
      on E: Exception do
        Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
    end;
  finally
    FStreamRead.Free;
    readln;
  end;
end.
```

Commenting out the line:

```
Achar := char (FStreamRead.Read);
```

allows the copy to be done without error. The documentation states that if count is greater than zero in the `TStream.CopyFrom` method it performs the copy from the current position in the input stream which is what I need to achieve.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TStreamReader` internally uses buffering. You are simply not allowed to use the `BaseStream` from outside.

Comment: Thanks, will have to do it the long way then.